# What's a simple way to trim this group of data? (Java)

Tags: java, json, class, arraylist

I'm practicing playing around with simple JSON data in Java and I've gotten a bit stuck.

So let's say I'm a baker and I have some data on my various products over the years. For, example I have three products: cake, bagels, and cookies. My data is collected over a yearly basis, so an example JSON data set could be something like:

```
[ {"name": "cake", "consumers": 200, "tastiness": 8.0}, {"name": "cake", "consumers": 220, "tastiness": 8.3}, {"name": "bagel", "consumers": 1000, "tastiness": 6.4}, {"name": "bagel", "consumers": 1200, "tastiness": 7.5}, {"name": "bagel", "consumers": 800, "tastiness": 5.7}, {"name": "cookie", "consumers": 500, "tastiness": 9.6} ]
```

As you can see, there are two entries of "cake" to signal cake being around for two years, three entries of "bagel" to signal bagels being around for three years, etc.

I'd like to condense this data to get the weighted average tastiness for each product. For example, the average tastiness for cake is (8.0*200 + 8.3*220)/(200+220) = 8.157, so I'd want my new set to contain a data entry with value ("cake", 8.157), in addition to the corresponding average tastiness for bagels and cookies.

Parsing through the JSON data and extracting the values I want is trivial, but what I'm struggling with is the best method to extract/condensing the data values with the same name and getting the average tastiness.

So far, I've considered making arrayLists for names, consumerNumbers, and tastiness, but I realized that might be a bit messy and inconvenient.

I'm currently considering making a separate class called "Product" with properties "name", "consumers", and "tastiness", and then creating a *single* `arrayList<Product>`. However, I'm stuck on how I'd best iterate through the arrayList of products and grab the Products with identical names and calculating the weighted average.

I am aware that there probably exists an incredibly easy and simple solution to my issue but it's just not coming to me at the moment, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have multiple kinds of products and an arbitrary number of groups, that you want to work on.

Have you considered using a `Map`? You could use something like `Map<String, List<Product>>`

You can build the map by using Java 8 streams (stream the `List<Product>`) and grouping over the product name.

Finally, you can for-each over the `keySet` of the map and the List of Products in the `List`

Example:

```java
   List<Product> products = buildProductsList();
   Map<String, List<Product>> productsGroupedByName = products.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getName));
   for(String name : productsGroupedByName.keySet()) {
      System.out.println("The name is: " + name);
      for (Product product : productsGroupedByName.get(name)) {
          // do something with the products
      }
   }
```

Comment: where does your "groupingBy" come from?

Comment: It's from the Collectors package. `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;`

Comment: ah right, thanks. For the first for each loop, getting the name from the productsGroupedByName, I get a "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" red underline, which is weird since aren't Maps iterable?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add keySet to it. It should read `for(String name : productsGroupedByName.keySet())` - and I have also updated my answer.

Comment: Any tips on how I'd get the weighted average of tastiness in an efficient manner? Since I've for-each'd the products, do I go through each product and store the consumers and tastiness values into a separate list until the name changes, then perform the weighted average calculations separately for each of the lists I create? Or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2):

I think your idea to create a container class with the said properties is a good idea.

With a combination of `groupingBy` and `reducing` from the `java.util.stream.Collectors` class, you can achieve this.

We're first defining a class which will hold our data:

```
public class SugarStats {
    private String name;
    private long consumers;
    private double tastiness;

    // Constructor(name, consumers, tastiness) and getters left out for brevity
}
```

We will be using this container class to give us the average, so we're going to add a method:

```
public double getAverageTastiness() {
    return this.tastiness / this.consumers;
}
```

Further, I assume that the conversion from JSON to a POJO is already made, and that your data looks like this:

```
List<SugarStats> stats = Arrays.asList(
    new SugarStats("cake", 200, 8.0),
    new SugarStats("cake", 220, 8.3),
    new SugarStats("bagel", 1000, 6.4),
    new SugarStats("bagel", 1200, 7.5),
    new SugarStats("bagel", 800, 5.7),
    new SugarStats("cookie", 500, 9.6));
```

Then we will do the following:

1. We're going to stream over the list:

   ```
   stats.stream()
   ```
2. then we are going to sum up the total tastiness score for each `SugarStats`, instead of the score of a single entry:

   ```
   .map(t -> new SugarStats(t.getName(), t.getConsumers(), t.getConsumers() * t.getTastiness()))
   ```

   For instance, the *cookie* sugarstats instance now has a tastiness of *`500 * 9.6 = 4800`*.
3. Then we're collecting the results, grouping by name. This would normally return a `Map` with the `name` as the key and a `List<SugarStats>` with all values. However, we're not interested in a `List`, we're only interested in the averages. So we're providing a *reducing* downstream collector, which gathers all SugarStats and combines them totalling the number of consumers and the tastiness.

   For instance, `new SugarStats("cake", 200, 1600.0) + new SugarStats("cake", 220, 1826.0)` will become `new SugarStats("cake", 420, 3426)`.

   ```
   .collect(groupingBy(t -> t.getName(),
       reducing(
           new SugarStats("", 0, 0),
           (p1, p2) -> new SugarStats(
               p2.getName(),
               p1.getConsumers() + p2.getConsumers(),
               p1.getTastiness() + p2.getTastiness()
           )
       )
   ));
   ```

And now we can get the tastinesses:

```
result.values().stream()
    .forEach(t -> System.out.println(t.getName() + ": " + t.getAverageTastiness()));
```

[Ideone example here](http://ideone.com/251pTm).